# How is my reputation being calculated for user's flair?

Tags: discussion, support

I got the idea for adding my reputation on my site from https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair.

But I am confused about its calculation. This is my reputation image -

[image: My profile from stackoverflow.com/users/flair]

How is this reputation calculated? As I have too many accounts.

- Stackoverflow.com
- superuser.com
- meta.stackoverflow.com
- serverfault.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It calculates and tracks **only the sites you have 200+ rep and active on** - the combined user flair that is.

Of all of your accounts, you have 200+ on only four; the four seen on your flair: Stack Overflow (2165), Super User (985), Meta Stack Overflow (714), and Area 51 (291).